# iText PdfTemplate duplication

Tags: c#, itext

I have created PdfTemplate with some contour. Now i want to duplicate it 4 times and place different shapes on each of them. What I am trying now is:

```
PdfTemplate[] oRTA = new PdfTemplate[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
     oRTA[i] = (PdfTemplate)oTemplate.GetDuplicate(false);
}
```

Where oTemplate is my standard PdfTemplate object. Problem can be that I can't use overwritten GetDuplicate method, so i have to cast it (dunno why). I am trying this with simple points:

```
oRTA[iTemplateIndex].Circle(oCmp.iXLocation, oCmp.iYLocation, 0.1f);
oRTA[iTemplateIndex].Stroke();
```

In result I've got nothing printed. Attempt with:

```
oTemplate.Circle(oCmp.iXLocation, oCmp.iYLocation, 0.1f);
oTemplate.Stroke();
```

works.

Comment: As was already explained on the iText mailing-list, it's unclear why you'd want to duplicate a `PdfTemplate` instance. You're probably using `PdfTemplate` to avoid redundancy. Duplicating an instance instead of reusing it, will introduce redundancy.

Comment: I am using `PdfTemplate` because I found it to be simple to use and fulfill my needs. I want to print 4 Printed Circuit Boards. I draw board's shape into one template. Now I want to duplicate this shape 4 times and place different components on every of them (like SMD on one, THT on another etc...)

Comment: Reuse the original PdfTemplates and add another PdfTemplate on top of them. That keeps the size of your PDF reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is not to duplicate your Template but to create it 4 times (4 different `PdfTemplate` objects) and then add what you need to every one of them. I know maybe it is now the best option but it work as it should. Solution given by Bruno Lowagie seems to be adequate too :)